# Changing The Current Time of a JavaScript Audio Object, When Getting the audio file from a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, header, mp3

I have built a PHP script that sends *.MP3 files form outside the public_html directory,
it works OK and sends the file. The problem is that I have a JavaScript script which should change the current time of the audio file (`audioFile.currentTime = 25`;).
When I do this(Get the file from inside the public_html directory), it works:

```
// JavaScript:
var audioFile = new Audio("https://www.website.com/files/audioFile.mp3");
audioFile.play();
audioFile.currentTime = 15;
```

But, when I try to get the file from the following PHP script it sends the file OK. But, I can't change the "currentTime" using JavaScript

```
<?php
     // This PHP file is public www.website.com/getAudioFile.php/
     $fileLocation = "../audioFiles/audioFile.mp3";
     if (file_exists($fileLocation))
     {
          header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
          header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
          header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
          header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
          readfile($file);
     }

?>
```

This is the JavaScript within which I tried to change the audio file currentTime:

```
    <script>
         var audioFile = new Audio("www.website.com/getAudioFile.php");
         audioFile.play();
         audioFile.currentTime = 15;
    </script>
```

Each time I use `object.currentTime = 15`, the audio files plays from the start.

If anyone knows what headers I should send or anything else I should do, please let me know how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after I have posted this question, I found the solution to the problem.
In order to make the script work you will need to add the `header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');`

Like this:

```
<?php
     // This PHP file is public www.website.com/getAudioFile.php/
     $fileLocation = "../audioFiles/audioFile.mp3";
     if (file_exists($fileLocation))
     {
          header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
          header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
          header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
          header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
          header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
          readfile($file);
     }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You should bind **canplay** event from Audio component and in this callback set currentTime property.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplay.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but right after I have posted this question I found the solution. In case you would ever run into the same problem, You just need to add the Accept-Ranges header header('Accept-Ranges: bytes') in the PHP script.

Comment: @JosephVigdorovich, if you have an answer, please post it as an answer to this question so that everyone can share in your knowledge. That is the purpose of Stack Overlow. Thanks.